# how to hide radio button value in jsp page while using <s:radio> tag

Tags: html, struts2

Recently I have used to  tag for displaying radio button in the page , but as per the requirement I don't want show the value in the front end, just need to visible a radio button.

used code in Struts2:

```
<s:radio label="id" name="requestId" list="requestId" value="" />
```

here getting value with radio button.

but require only radio button, but value should be mapped to property while submit.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution :

```
<input type="radio" name="selectedNMRequestId" value="<s:property value='requestId'/>"/>
```

Its working fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Or `value="${requestId}"`

Comment: Thank you Dave, for your response . In my case the mentioned syntax not working .its taking as string while form submit.

Comment: Then you don't have JSP EL enabled, which IMO you should, because it cleans things up significantly. YMMV.